# Allow www-data to perform specific commands

Tags: permissions, sudo, php, git

I need a PHP script to perform `git pull` however I am not naive enough to give it permissions on `git`. I've wrapped `git pull` in a script which `www-data` has permissions for, but I'm not sure how to give the script permissions on `git` itself:

```
$ sudo tail -n1 /etc/sudoers
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/php-scripts/git-pull

$ cat /home/php-scripts/git-pull
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/git pull

$ ls -la /home | grep php-scripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Sep  3 09:26 php-scripts

$ ls -la /home/php-scripts/git-pull
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 30 Sep  3 08:44 /home/php-scripts/git-pull

$ cat /var/www/public_html/git-wrapper.php
<?php

$output = array();
$value = 0;
exec("/home/php-scripts/git-pull", $output, $value);

echo "<pre>";  
echo "Return Value: {$value}\n";

foreach ( $output as $o) {
    echo $o."\n";
}

?>
```

Note that `/var/www/public_html/` is in fact a git repository. I often perform `git pull` in that directory from the CLI. However, when I call this script in a web browser I see that the files were not updated via `git pull` and the following is output to the browser:

```
Return Value: 1
```

This is on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Git 1.7.9.5. The remote repository is on the same server.

Comment: `/usr/bin/git pull >/tmp/git.log 2>&1` and see what the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script runs under `www-data:www-data` I suppose. You have to run the `git pull` with a user that have a write permission on your cloned repository. You have configured `sudo`, but you don't call it anywhere which doesn't make much sense (not saying you need to do that at all). Verify under what user you are running and then switch to appropriate one if needed and adjust permissions on your cloned repository accordingly.